# Javascript regular expression to reduce 'n' same consecutive characters to single character in a given string

Tags: javascript, regex, string-formatting

**Ex:**

```
var str = "......43.....DF.67....89...........";
while(str.search(/(..)/g) > -1) {
   str = str.replace(/(..)/g, '.');
}
str = str.replace('.', '-');
```

**Output**: -43-DF-67-89-

Steps 01: I am replacing two '.' (i.e., '..') to one '.' using regular expression.
Steps 02: If no more two '.', then finally I am replacing one '.' with '-'

But I need to achieve in one step without loops.

Comment: What do you mean by 'masked'? Does it have a special meaning?

Comment: For Ex: In UI while displaying CC we will display with masted characters and while sending back to api we need to convert with wild character. Any suggestion pls let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can escape the period and use the + operator to indicate one or more periods.

```js
var str = "......43.....DF.67....89...........";

str = str.replace(/\.+/g, '-');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Nice and clean. Me likes!